# Using tensorflow for sequence tagging : Synced sequence input and output

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to use Tensorflow for sequence tagging namely Part of Speech tagging. I tried to use the same model outlined here: http://tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq/index.md (which outlines a model to translate English to French).

Since in tagging, the input sequence and output sequence have exactly the same length, I configured the buckets so that input and output sequences have same length and tried to learn a POS tagger using this model on ConLL 2000.

However it seems that the decoder sometimes outputs a taggedsequence shorter than the input sequence (it seems to feel that the EOS tag appears prematurely)

For example:
**He reckons the current account deficit will narrow to only # 1.8 billion in September .**

The above sentence is tokenized to have 18 tokens which gets padded to 20 (due to bucketing).

When asked to decode the above, the decoder spits out the following:

**PRP VBD DT JJ JJ NN MD VB TO VB DT NN IN NN . _EOS . _EOS CD CD**

So here it ends the sequence (EOS) after 15 tokens not 18.

How can I force the sequence to learn that the decoded sequence should be the same length as the encoded one in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If your input and output sequences are the same length you probably want something simpler than a seq2seq model (since handling *different* sequence lengths is one of it's strengths)

Have you tried just training (word -> tag) ?

[image: tokens to tags]

note: that for something like pos tagging where there is clear signal from tokens on either side you'll definitely get a benefit from a bidirectional net.

[image: bidir net]

If you want to go all crazy there would be some fun character level variants too where you only emit the tag at the token boundary (the rationale being that pos tagging benefits from character level features; e.g. things like out of vocab names). So many variants to try! :D

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Is there some boiler plate code I can use to build the first model (word->tag). I believe ptb code in tensor flow does something very similar (predicting the next word). I was wondering if I could use adapt that to predict tags.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of specifying an end of sequence parameter. The translate demo uses a flag `<EOS>` to determine the end of sequence. However, you can also specify end of sequence by counting the number of expected words in the output. In the lines 225-227 of the `translate.py`:

```
# If there is an EOS symbol in outputs, cut them at that point.
if data_utils.EOS_ID in outputs:
    outputs = outputs[:outputs.index(data_utils.EOS_ID)]
```

You can see that outputs are being cut off whenever `<EOS>` is encountered. You can easily tweak it to constrain the number of output words. You might also consider getting rid of `<EOS>` flag altogether while training, considering your application.

Answer (score 0):

I came to the same problem. At the end I found ptb_word_lm.py example in tensorflow's examples is exactly what we need for tokenization, NER and POS tagging.

If you look into details of the language model example, you can find out that it treats the input character sequence as X and right shift X for 1 space as Y. It is exactly what fixed length sequence labeling needs.