# Tensorflow: LSTM when each part of a sequence belongs to a class?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement LSTM in Tensorflow, but my data is a bit "untraditional" in the following way:
Each hour of the day, one of five events can happen. I want to feed sequences of 24 hours into my LSTM.

The thing is, I need it to output a target class for each element of each sequence.

This has to be possible with LSTM's, right? The only examples of TF implementations of LSTM's have been just feeding a sequence and getting a target class for that sequence.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Element level classification is definitely possible in TF.
   For example, take a look at this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737611/using-tensorflow-for-sequence-tagging-synced-sequence-input-and-output) about POS-tagging and the references therein. (if the reference seems too complicated, I would search for other TF references about POS tagging).
2. Your question does not describe how sequences differ one from another. What are the actual elements in an input sequence? The hours 1..24?